# OpenSSL in ruby: PKCS#8 format for private key

Tags: ruby, openssl

I've created an RSA private key in ruby with:

```
require 'openssl'
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(1024)
```

I can get the key in PEM or DER formats:

```
key.to_pem
key.to_der
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to get it into PKCS#8 format.  The best I've come up with is to call out to openssl in another process:

```
require 'open3'
Open3.popen3('openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -passout pass:password') do |stdin,  stdout, stderr|
  stdin.write(key.to_pem)
  unless (err = stderr.read).empty? then raise err end
  stdout.read
end
```

There must be a better way that I just can't find.  Does the OpenSSL class library in ruby have a mechanism for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There is support [in Ruby trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/b99775b163ce44079c1f8727ce9b4ed8bb03489d#diff-bae6e18b74ab1f890ac3e06a1aae16a2R366) for exporting private keys to PKCS#8 format, using the new `private_to_pem` and `private_to_der` methods on `OpenSSL::PKey::PKey` (and subclasses).  So Real Soon Now, or Right Now if you like living on the bleeding edge, we'll finally be able to write out PKCS#8 keys natively.